# What's the girl's name?

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking

Here is what happened:

He sailed along 25 reefs, passing 1 chameleon, in order to see her sweet bosoms.

What's her name?

Hint:

> She is not a goddess.

Hint 2:

> Her name is one word, a couple of words in the sentence refer to her name.

Hint 3:

> The poisoned chalice was that after he arrived at the almost bare island and found her, she was only a crippled girl lying on the ground.

Comment: Username checks out.

Comment: It's Jane. He wasn't picky about the name.

Comment: You've asked a number of questions which have required a degree of "guess what I'm thinking" without sufficient clueing (even in hints) to point people in the right direction. While they seem like decent questions, the fact that users are coming up with answers that are met only with "nope, that's not what I was thinking" suggests that the puzzles could be better constructed to lead solvers toward the right answer

Comment: @tmpearce Hi! Thanks for your interest and suggestion! Accordingly, I reviewed this question, but I don't see a way (nor a reason) to change its construction. Also, I will try to provide more helpful responses to answers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user has been deleted.

Comment: What was the answer then?

Answer (score 15):

Her name is:

> Carmenta, Roman Goddess of Childbirth.

Explanation:

> The English alphabet has 26 letters, 25 of which behave either as consonants or vowels, and one, Y, behaves as both - the chameleon. But how do we get from the alphabet to bosoms? The English alphabet is adapted from the Latin alphabet, and legend has it that Carmenta, the Goddess of childbirth, changed many letters of the Greek alphabet to give us the Latin alphabet.

Attempt #2

Her name is:

> Penelope, wife of Odysseus. He is Odysseus.

Explanation:

> tmpearce pointed out in their answer that the Greek Isles are a great destination for reef snorkeling. But who is the Chameleon? The goddess Athena appears throughout the Odyssey in many different forms to assist Odysseus on his quest to be reunited with his wife's sweet bosoms.

Attempt #3, we're getting more far fetched here. Her name is:

> India.

Explanation:

> In August, 1803, three ships named *Porpoise, Cato,* and *Bridgewater* set sail for India from Sydney, Australia. On their way past the Great Barrier Reef, the navigated through an area today known as Wreck Reefs (25 reefs clue). The Porpoise and the Cato ran aground on a shoal amidst the reefs (chameleon clue, shoals disappear and reappear), and beat against the reef until they sank. Sadly, I am not aware of any particular treasure known as the Bosom of India that would have made this solution a better fit. But what we do know is that India in the early 1800s was an enormous exporter of textiles, and *bosom* can refer to the portion of a lady's dress which contains her bosom, so these ships were sailing to find bosoms from India for their bosoms in Australia.

Comment: I didn't know that, so thanks, but no, it is not that:)

Comment: I've read it,but I don't remember,didn't know, so thanks, but no, it is not the the correct answer :)

Comment: On to attempt #3 then I suppose. I'll be mad if someone else gets it.

Comment: these stories are inspiring even for the author to read the same stuff ->(that is why lateral thinking-knowledge puzzles are of a good kind, making the stuff more interactive.) From the solution point of view, your clues are very indirect,sometimes twice, three times indirect, while  the solution has a definite, direct clueing. I made a promise to give hints in response to constructive answers, I am just thinking about one at the moment:)

Comment: rot13(fur hfhnyyl jrnef oybffbzf orgjrra ure obfbzf)

Answer (score 9):

3rd Attempt

> Buttercup

Because

> Get ready... Utter - Definition 6. to express by written or printed words. (the man could be writing a letter) ,Synonym of Utter - Blooming (Relates to Hint - Blossom between her bosoms)

Finally

> Assuming B-cup can be considered a bosom, placing utter between B-cup is B-utter-cup or Buttercup.

2nd Attempt

> Catalina - Because there is a sailboat called a Catalina 25, Which probably goes 25 knots (reefs), or a list where you would have to pass a chameleon (another type of sailboat) in order to get to the Catalina. Also The name Catalina means pure, so I'm thinking she would have a big heart, or is a sweetheart.

First Answer

> Bea (for current English) Because Reef - verb- to shorten or bring inboard (a spar). So, going in reverse from Z, shortening the alphabet by 1 at each letter, including Y, which can be used as a consonant or vowel (chameleon), puts him at B. (note - He would have to start outside the alphabet and reef once before entering) Moreover The letter B could possibly be used to show a top-down view of cartoon-like bosoms. Possible (Possibly Beta or Beth for ancient language origins if the boat was also going backwards in time)

Comment: That's brilliant, I'll be surprised if this isn't it.

Comment: @F1Krazy, Thanks for the vote of confidence. We'll see I guess.

Comment: @ F1Krazy and MacGyver88 No, not Bea, Beth, Beta

Comment: @MacGyver88 Catalina, creative! sorry,but Catalina doesn't go 25 knots this time. Hint1 rot13(fur hfhnyyl jrnef oybffbzf orgjrra ure obfbzf) and hint2 rot13(n jbeq be n ahzore va gur fragrapr ersref gb n yrggre (rvgure gur zrnavat bs jevggra pbzzhavpngvba be nycunorg flzoby)

Comment: @MacGyver88 we should do a reverse riddle. Make up some stupid riddle, and then post the riddle as 10 valid answers and make everyone guess what the riddle was.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov That sounds pretty cool. I love and hate this answer, though.

Comment: I'm in the game:D

Comment: So, guys, listen to me. MacGyver will get 25 as it seems. The solution has not been found yet. Are you bored of it, and think this is just stupid, or wanna have another bounty, next is 100.

Comment: @Archipelago, I love this type of thing. That's why I'm constantly giving answers. You're good. You are a good questioner. No boredom here.

Comment: So, this isn't the answer?

Comment: I didn't even know that Buttercup is a name...  Alrite, next "season" coming up soon with constructive and informative hints.

Comment: As you wish. Yes. Buttercup is the name of a famous fictional princess.

Comment: Looks like you got half the bounty for having most upvotes *during* the bounty period. All mine came before the bounty :(

Comment: @Thomas, I saw that, too. Today was wild. Now, I'm stuck wondering what the answers are to 3 puzzles.

Answer (score 7):

I think the girl's name might be

> Aphrodite

Sailing through the

> Mediterranean sea, specifically near the Greek isles,

he would pass many reefs - in fact, it is a popular destination for scuba diving amongst the reefs! As part of the trip, he may pass by a "chameleon":

> The island of Cyprus, which is under (disputed) rule by multiple entities, and therefore has many flags with many colors

His final destination:

> The island of [Mykonos, Greece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mykonos), and a certain [famous pair](http://www.earthxplorer.com/blog/the-two-breasts-of-aphrodite-mykonos-greece-its-not-what-you-think) of [hills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breast-shaped_hill#/media/File:Hills_on_Mykonos.jpg) named for the girl, Aphrodite

Comment: Nice journey, what I don't see yet, which of these things led you to the name Aphrodite specifically. Her name is not Aphrodite.

Comment: @Archipelago Added the reference to the name (in the form of another link)

Comment: Nice! The name of the hills.

Comment: "*multiple entities, and therefore has many flags*" - only two. Btw, that island you mention (the disputed one, not the final one) is supposed to be the birthplace of the girl you mention.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I was thinking of the UN and (historical + ?administrative zone) UK involvement too. I wasn't aware of the supposed birthplace origins there...

Comment: and Cyprus is one of the few (4) regions in Europe where the chameleon (not the "chameleon") is autochthonous

Answer (score 7):

Her name is

> Em (short for Emily or Emma)

He sailed along 25 reefs,

> Referring to the first 25 letters on a QWERTY keyboard, to arrive at M

passing 1 chameleon,

> Referring to the caps lock key, which changes color

in order to see her sweet bosoms.

> Capital 'M' looks like a nice pointy pair of breasts from birds eye view

Hint

> *a couple of words in the sentence refer to her name.* There are two words in the sentence containing the letter M

Comment: upvoted,nice abstract thinking but her name is not EM

Answer (score 6):

The girls name is:

> Anastasia Steele (from Fifty Shades of Grey)

The reason is:

> He follows the rope which has several **reef** knots tied in it, which leads to a **chameleon** which is obviously some kind of adult toy and the **bosoms** speak for themselves. This is because she likes to be tied up.

Comment: If this is it, I’m honestly proud I didn’t, nor ever would have, figured it out.

Comment: @Thomas If this is it I'd be surprised myself!

Comment: It is unfortunate to you that the original answer is not that funny, at the same time it is fortunate to me haha:)

Answer (score 5):

Here is my guess:

> I think we are actually on a sea voyage.

*He sailed along 25 reefs*

> I believe this refers to the atolls of the Maldives although [wikipedia says there are 26](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atolls_of_the_Maldives).

*passing 1 chameleon*

> This likely refers to Madagascar, home to more than [half of the world's chameleons](https://www.pbs.org/edens/madagascar/creature3.htm)

So that takes us to

> south africa

Bringing in sweet bosoms, I think the girl's name is

> Zozibini Tunzi, who is Miss South Africa and just been [crowned Miss Universe 2019](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/miss-south-africa-crowned-miss-universe-2019-steve-harvey-atlanta-pag)

Since it's not her, assuming I got the country correct, my second guess is

> Candice Swanepoel who is a south african supermodel

Comment: Her name is not Zozibini Tunzi.

Comment: Is the logic totally wrong, or just a different girl? Do I get a hint? :)

Comment: Totally wrong, and yes!: rot13(fur hfhnyyl jrnef oybffbzf orgjrra ure obfbzf)

Answer (score 3):

I think the girls name is

> Minerva

Explanation

> Taking the reef part literally. He sailed past 25 reefs. Wikipedias list of reefs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_reefs. If he were to sail *past* 25 reefs, the 26th on the list is Minerva Reef

Explanation Part 2

> The "sweet bosoms" line. A synonym for bosoms is 'bust' which could be a reference to the [Bronze bust of Minerva](https://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection/search/246688)

Still working on the other other part of the puzzle

> The chameleon could perhaps be a reference to many Roman gods having Greek counterparts or alternatively that the god could apparently shape shift. Still researching

Comment: Continue researching. rot13(Cevingr uvag: qba'g ybbx sbe gur anzr "ba gur Bylzchf")

Answer (score 3):

Her name is

> what

I got it from the Hint 2 that apart from whatever he actually did to see her, a couple of words in the sentence refer to her name. And I don't know how to connect the things he did to see her to the answer. :(

Comment: I hope this isn't the answer... ([obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/169/))

Comment: You get an upvote from me, because, as stupid as it is, your answer makes sense in light of the EIGHT well thought out answers that have been wrong.

Comment: Which is not to say your answer is stupid, obviously I think the riddle is stupid at this point.

Comment: It is frustrating to me to have to say: No, her name is not what. If only it would be what...:!   (:D)

Answer (score 3):

Is her name

> Uptown Girl?

He sailed along 25 reefs

> In October 1983 Uptown Girl by Billy Joel was at #25 on the billboard top singles.

Passing 1 chameleon

> At the same time in October 1983 the song Karma Chameleon was at #1 on the billboard top singles. Then the next week it was passed by Uptown Girl which took the #1 spot.

In order to see her sweet bosoms

> No idea here

Answer (score 0):

Her name is......

> sweet bosoms

Comment: Try to google search sweet bosoms, click images (safesearch off) and pick a name, at least ;)

Comment: Doing so is NSFW, obviously.